# Display message when the cursor is hovering a canvas in Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, events, canvas

So i have these lines of code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")


canvas = Canvas(root, width=150, height=150, bg="black", bd=2, relief="ridge")
canvas.place(x=20, y=20)

A = canvas.create_oval(20,20,30,30, outline='grey', fill="grey")

B = canvas.create_oval(130,130,140,140, outline='grey', fill="grey")

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to find out how I could show a text when im hovering over a canvas. For example, when my mouse is hovering the first circle, the text should say "A" and for the second circle, it should say "B".

I found a code that does what I want to do but it's with text and I don't know how to make it work with a canvas too:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.l1 = tk.Label(self, text="Hover over me")
        self.l2 = tk.Label(self, text="", width=40)
        self.l1.pack(side="top")
        self.l2.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.l1.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.l1.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.l2.configure(text="Hello world")

    def on_leave(self, enter):
        self.l2.configure(text="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
    root.mainloop()
```

In addition, let's say i have another .py file in which I want to assign both A and B canvases a different variables from that .py file and have it show in the text config. For example: In the .py file i have the variables

```
for_A = 123
for_B = 456
```

How can I make it look such as when I'm hovering the A canvas it shows something like this:

```
 A 
123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to add `tag` option in `canvas.create_oval(...)`:

```py
A = canvas.create_oval(20,20,30,30, outline='grey', fill="grey", tag="A")
B = canvas.create_oval(130,130,140,140, outline='grey', fill="grey", tag="B")
```

2. create a label to show the circle name:

```py
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.place(x=200, y=20, anchor="nw")
```

3. use `canvas.tag_bind()` to bind `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events on the two circles:

```py
def on_enter(e):
    # find the canvas item below mouse cursor
    item = canvas.find_withtag("current")
    # get the tags for the item
    tags = canvas.gettags(item)
    # show it using the label
    lbl.config(text=tags[0])

def on_leave(e):
    # clear the label text
    lbl.config(text="")

for item in (A, B):
    canvas.tag_bind(item, "<Enter>", on_enter)
    canvas.tag_bind(item, "<Leave>", on_leave)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
In addition, let's say i have another .py file in which I want to assign both A and B canvases a different variables from that .py file and have it show in the text config.

For example: In the .py file i have the variables
```
for_A = 123
for_B = 456
```
How can I make it look such as when I'm hovering the A canvas it shows something like this:
```
  A  
123
```

Comment: @cockroachman First update the `tag` option: `A = canvas.create_oval(..., tag=("A", for_A))`, then use `lbl.config(text=' '.join(tags[:-1])`.